# silverlight datepicker show original 'incorrect date' text 

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I'm using the Silverlight Toolkit DatePicker control.

If an user enters an invalid format date for example foo/bar/2001 then the DatePicker automatically 'ignores' the date and sets it back to the last date.

This behaviour is fine, except I'd like to actually show the date in error to the user (not corrected) and display some validation message etc so the user knows what the issue is

Does anyone have a snip or sample I can use that works in this way?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the [DateValidationError event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.datevalidationerror.aspx). [Calendar control in Silverlight using C#](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/Blogs/3787/calendar-control-in-silverlight-using-C-Sharp.aspx) has a bit of sample code showing how the event handler could be wired up.

Comment: Thanks, seems like the best approach without too much messing about. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey Ron, i have the same exact problem. What was the solution? Unfortunately the second link doesn't work and i tried all sorts of things to get the event wired up to stop the date change but it still changes it. Any ideas or examples would be helpful. thanks.

Comment: Hi there, well its been well over a year so i struggled to find the offending code. However, i tracked down the project and it seems that I ended up writing some codebehind in frustration that resets SelectedDate back to the original value from datacontext in the event that the SelectionChangedEventArgs date value is null. ie **if (((DatePicker)sender).SelectedDate == null) ((DatePicker)sender).SelectedDate = _dataContext.PeriodStart;** Really not sure this helps and can't verify this now as too long gone

Comment: Hey Ron! Thanks for the answer. I need to actually leave whatever the user entered into the field intact and prompt a validation error. Thank you thought for taking the time of looking it up. :)